# VC++ How to change a character at a specific position within a string?

Tags: string, c++-cli

Visual C++: I want to set the 3rd character in a string to `'C'`.

If I try

```
String^ s1="XXXXXX";
s1[2]="C";
```

The compiler says:

```
'System::String::default': property does not have a 'set' method
```

Any idea?

Comment: The variable `s1` is not a `String` object, it's a managed *pointer* to a `String` object.

Answer (score 3):

The System::String type is *immutable*, an expensive word that just means that it doesn't have a single method or property that lets you change the string after it is created.  That gives the type *very* desirable behavior.  It is always thread-safe and you can readily pass a string to a function without having to worry that the function is going to change it.  Or in other words, it behaves like a *value*, just like an *int*.

But the other side of the medal is that it won't let you do what you want to do, the compiler reminds you that it isn't possible.  You have to create a *new* string object.  The Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace has a convenience method for that, but everybody gets their underwear in a bundle when they see that name.  So write it explicitly:

```
  String^ s1="XXXXXX";
  s1 = s1->SubString(0, 2) + 'C' + s1->SubString(3);
```

Or more universally:

```
  String^ ReplaceAt(String^ str, String^ subst, int index)
  {
      return str->Substring(0, index) + subst + str->Substring(index + subst->Length);
  }
```

If you are doing at lot of this, repeatedly creating string objects isn't very cheap, then you want to use a StringBuilder instead.

Comment: Thanks all. Explains it all. I just have to use standard C++, didn't know that the system name space is so different. I have programmed a lot in C++, but the last time in the 1980s! Much less confusing back then

Comment: "I just have to use standard C++": This is *not* standard C++! C++/CLI is a completely different beast.

Answer (score 1):

C++/CLI `String`'s are immutable, so once created you can't change their content, as your error message suggests.

The `s1[2]='C';` syntax (note the *single quote* around the character C, not double quote) would work fine for standard C++ **`std::string`**.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the conversion in the native string and convert it back to managed string.

```
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

System::String^ managed = "XXXXXX";
std::string unmanaged = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(managed);

unmanaged[2]='C';

System::String^ managed2 = String(unmanaged.c_str());
```

Hope that helps,